# GoogleMap crashes on 2.3.7 android

Tags: android

The following code crashes in 2.3.7 but it won't in api 19.
Here is the Java code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {
    Button normal, satellite, terrain, hybrid, none;
    private GoogleMap gMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initiator();
    }

    private void initiator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        gMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        normal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.normalmap);
        hybrid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hybridmap);
        terrain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.terrainmap);
        satellite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.satellitemap);
        none = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nonemap);
        normal.setOnClickListener(this);
        hybrid.setOnClickListener(this);
        terrain.setOnClickListener(this);
        satellite.setOnClickListener(this);
        none.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.normalmap:
            gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            break;
        case R.id.hybridmap:
            gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            break;
        case R.id.terrainmap:
            gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            break;
        case R.id.satellitemap:
            gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            break;
        case R.id.nonemap:
            gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for xml. If I change "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" to "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" then it will crash on api level 19 emulator.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/normalmap"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Normal"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hybridmap"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hybrid"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/satellitemap"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Satellite"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/terrainmap"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Terrain"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nonemap"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="None"
            android:layout_weight="2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there an alternative to it for 2.3.7?

Comment: update Question with Log Cat

Comment: You could use the broadly similar Osmdroid, http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to commit the following changes:

Change the map object in your layout:

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

To this:

```
 <fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And as said get the `SupportMapFragment` instead of the `MapFragment` object in code, using:

```
gMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

In case of any problems you can also use this blog post guide I wrote on this topic:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: @SaadZaheer, I'm glad you found it useful : )

Answer (score 0):

It may be, because you are not using a SupportMapFragment. Try to change your code to this:

```
 gMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

To use the SupportMapFragment you need to include the support-v4 library. More info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html

Comment: It says cannot cast from Fragment to SupportMapFragment

Comment: well, read the documentation. Of course, that's not possible, because SupportMapFragment is a Fragment and not the other way around. See the post of @Emil Adz for your changes in your layout xml. You must switch your whole code to using SupportMapFragment. The easiest way to do this should be to remove any imports of MapFragment and Fragment. Your IDE will then tell you where to fix things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SupportMapFragment` both in your XML and your activity code for it to work. You can find plenty of examples on this on the web.

Check this link for example:

http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-supportmapfragment-example/

Comment: cannot cast from Fragment to SupportMapFragment

Comment: check the link for example